# Restrict ansible features to an older version?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In my work environment I have already upgraded to a newer ansible version than what co-workers have. By accident I keep using features that their version does not have yet.

Is there a way to prevent this on my side in that I force ansible to pretend it is actually an older version?

Comment: any feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python virtual environments to handle multiple ansible versions. I use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage virtualenvs. Here is how you can do it in bash on Linux:

**Install pyenv:**

You can change paths according to your liking if you don't want default paths.

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ${HOME}/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
echo 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then  eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

**Install pyenv virtualenv for user:**

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git ${HOME}/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

**Initialize pyenv environment for current shell**

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

**Install older ansible in one virtualenv:**

```
pyenv virtualenv old_env
pyenv activate old_env
pip install ansible==2.4
```

**Install newer ansible in other virtualenv:**

```
pyenv virtualenv new_env
pyenv activate new_env
pip install ansible==2.7
```

**Daily Usage:**

You can switch between virtualenvs whenver you want. e.g. to switch to old ansible virtualenv and check ansible version, you can do like this:

```
pyenv activate old_env
ansible --version
```